# Jquery Content slider with slide when hover over div. jquery Cycle

Tags: jquery, hover, cycle, fade, pager

Ok here we go, this is the first time i ever ask a question here. up until now i have just read and learned a lot for the past few years.

anyway this is what i'm trying to accomplish:

i want to have a content slider wich autoloops and fades. but also connect this to different div's on the same page.

so  i've been looking at a lot of the different jquery (content) sliders today. and decided to work with the jquery cycle plugin. this almost does work like i want it.

but after more then 4 hours of searching the web, and trying different solutions, i guess it's time to admit i won't figure this one out by myself.

i'm stuck with the pageranchorbuilder, how can i do this properly? or where do i go from here? i hope this is clear enough...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#nav { margin: 5px; }
#nav a { margin: 5px; padding: 3px 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #fc0; text-decoration: none }
#nav a.activeSlide { background: #ea0 }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }
#slideshow { text-align:left; margin-bottom:100px;}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.80.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
       fx:    'fade', 
    speed:  2500 ,
        pager:      '#nav',
        pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
        allowPagerClickBubble: true,
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(i, el) {
            return '<div style="float:left;height:200px;width:100px;"><a href="' + el.src + '"><img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach'+ (i+1) +'.jpg" width="100" height:"100"/></a></div>';
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="slideshow" class="pics">
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach6.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach7.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        </div>


<div id="nav"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to have a content slider wich autoloops and fades. but also connect this to different div's on the same page.

Could you go into a more detail about what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: i was afraid this would happen, i just don't now how to explain this in more detail, english isn't my first language. the auto loop and fade stuff is done with the cycle plugin, in my example code the pageranchorbuilder does make the other div's i am talking about. it just doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code.

I see that the hover does not work consistently

I tried using the follwing version of the cycle script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
```

and it now works consistently - hopefully the way you want.

I used that script as that is what they use on the jquery cycle demo pages.

I tried downloading the script called: jquery.cycle.all.latest.min.js from the download page and it doesn't work, so not sure what the differences in the scripts are.

Comment: thanx! i'll test your suggestion.